# invalid datatypes when creating table with date and time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am encountering a problem when creating the following table in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE observacion (
carretera VARCHAR2(6), 
sentido VARCHAR2(3),
km NUMBER(3,0),
fecha DATE,
hora TIME,
matricula VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL,
vin VARCHAR2(17) NOT NULL,
velocidad NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_observacion PRIMARY KEY (carretera, sentido, km, fecha, hora),
CONSTRAINT FK_radar FOREIGN KEY (carretera, sentido, km) REFERENCES radar (carretera, sentido, km),
CONSTRAINT FK_vehiculo FOREIGN KEY (matricula, vin) REFERENCES vehiculo (matricula, vin) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

The error I get is this:

```
   ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I need that fecha and hora have DATE and TIME datatypes, but I think that's the problem. Can anyone help me, please? Thank you :)

*EDIT*

This is the incoming data that I need to import from one database to another:

```
INSERT INTO megatable VALUES ('6205AIA', 'OQI29527Q44741473', 'Seta', 'Champi', '2200', 'verde', '2005-11-02', '2010-06-26', 'Leila', 'Conza', 'Sanchez', 'Calle de los Tulipanes, N 126, 27306', 'Hayedo de las Caballerizas', NULL, NULL, '1980-04-24', '51464893R', 'Gabriel Enrique', 'Orejuela', 'Herbada', 'Calle Orfebres, N 51, 23734', 'Sotolemures de los Buhos', '555298803', 'G.E.O.H.@servcorreo.uctreseme.edu', '1962-11-09', '69049869M', 'C', '1998-04-07', 49, 'A1', 120, 242, 'ASC', 100, **'2010-04-11', '22:45:38.75'**, 94);
```

All this data is type VARCHAR2(50)

As you can see, here there is only one relation, and what I want to do is separate all this atributes in different relations, so everything looks better. That's what I still want to store DATE and TIME separately, but I don't think keeping the VARCHAR datatype is the optimal choice.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "checking the documentation"? Here is a link to Oracle data type documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413 You will see that Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type - that's what the compiler is complaining about. In Oracle, the date and the time are stored together, in the `DATE` or perhaps `TIMESTAMP` data types.

Comment: thank you very much @mathguy!! The thing is that I wanted to store the date and the time separately because I receive from an older database this data, in varchars, separately. Can I take this 2 values and do some kind of TO_DATE with them???

Comment: That would be a good approach, yes. If for some reason you must keep them separate (which is rarely, if ever), it is possible but somewhat artificial. Much better to store both in a `DATE` column. Exactly how may involve `TO_DATE`. If you need help with that, it would be best to show the exact format (with examples) in which the source data comes in, with date and hour separately, and we can help you then combine them into an Oracle `date`.

Comment: I have added the example you asked me to, the values are the second and third to end in the query. Thanks @mathguy

Comment: Have you check the documentation whether type `DATE` and `TIME` exist in Oracle or not??  That's probably the first place you should have visited before posting a question here.

Comment: Thank you @eric, but this has already been said. Any other useful input? :)

Comment: OK, so the time has fractional seconds. If you must keep them (and I don't see why not), in Oracle that means using the `TIMESTAMP` data type, rather than `DATE`. I'll show how to do that in an Answer.

Comment: ok! thanks @mathguy :) in your answer could you explain as well how to get those values in 2 variables for the TO_DATE? instead of the raw values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP shows in an EDIT to the original question what the data looks like on input. All the values coming in are strings; and the date and time component, shown as the third and second values FROM THE END of the input, are `'2010-04-11'` and `'22:45:38.75'`.

Since the time has fractional seconds, the best data type in Oracle is `TIMESTAMP`. To get a single timestamp from these two strings:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(str1 || ' ' || str2, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
```

where `str1` and `str2` are arbitrary names I just made up for the two strings that are coming in; the code should be modified to reference those strings, in whatever manner is currently used to import the data.

To create a `DATE` data type, one option is to select a substring from the time-of-day component. I prefer another option: create the timestamp first, as shown above; then wrap it all within `cast ( ......   as date)`.

```
CAST (TO_TIMESTAMP(str1 || ' ' || str2, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff') AS DATE)
```

Comment: thank you!! could you explain how would you get str1 and str2 on a query in order to do that insertion in the new table??

Comment: @MartaLobo - how are you getting `fecha` and `hora` currently? I don't know how you are populating any of the other columns in the new table you are creating. Think about how you would populate `fecha` and `hora`; whatever expression you use for them, use those expressions instead of `str1` and `str2` in `TO_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: OK, now I get it, thank you very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following statement.

```
CREATE TABLE observacion (
carretera VARCHAR2(6), 
sentido VARCHAR2(3),
km NUMBER(3,0),
fecha DATE,
hora interval day (0) to second(0),
matricula VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL,
vin VARCHAR2(17) NOT NULL,
velocidad NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_observacion PRIMARY KEY (carretera, sentido, km, fecha, hora),
CONSTRAINT FK_radar FOREIGN KEY (carretera, sentido, km) REFERENCES radar 
(carretera, sentido, km),
CONSTRAINT FK_vehiculo FOREIGN KEY (matricula, vin) REFERENCES vehiculo 
(matricula, vin) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

The way you can insert the only the time is:

```
insert into observacion (...) values (TO_DSINTERVAL('0 15:00:14'));
```

Hope I could help you.
Talat